# Is this proof that $A \times B = \emptyset$ iff $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Can someone verify if this proof is correct, and if not, where can I improve? I'm kinda nervous that the part highlighted in red is circular reasoning.

**Proof:** We first show that if $A \times B = \emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$.

Let $(x,y)\in A\times B$. 
$\implies x \in A$ and $y \in B$. 
But $(x,y)\in\emptyset$ since $A \times B=\emptyset$. 
$\color{red}{\implies x \in \emptyset \:\text{or}\:y \in \emptyset}$ 
Since $x \in \emptyset$ and $x \in A$, or $y\in\emptyset$ and $y\in B$, $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$. 
$\therefore$ if $A \times B = \emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ is true.

Now we show that if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ then $A \times B = \emptyset$.

WLOG, assume $A=\emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.
Let $x\in A$ and $y \in B$.
Since $x \in A$ and $A = \emptyset$, $x \in \emptyset$.
By definition of the cartesian product of sets, $A \times B = \{(x,y)|x\in A \:\text{and}\:y\in B\}$.
But $x\in \emptyset$, so there are no coordinate pairs $(x,y)$ that exist.
$\implies A \times B$ has no elements, and $A\times B= \emptyset$.
$\therefore$ if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ then $A \times B = \emptyset$ is true.

$\therefore$ by TT, $A \times B = \emptyset$ iff $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ is true $\forall$ sets $A$ and $B$. $\blacksquare$

EDIT: Thank you for all your helpful feedback! I've posted a new and improved proof in the answers. Thoughts on that proof?

Comment: There are logical problems at the start of each section. In the first instance, we have the assumption $A\times B=\emptyset$ but then the next line is selecting $(x,y)$ from $A\times B$ (I assume the $=$ is a typo), which is already known to be impossible. In the second instance, changing "$A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$" to "$A=\emptyset$ and $B=\emptyset$" is not without loss of generality—that is a genuinely stronger assumption.

Comment: @GregMartin I see what you're saying. It seems the problem with this proof is that it's consistently picking out elements from the empty set, which like you said, is impossible. This may have been more effective as a proof by contrapositive for both sections. (And yes the $=$ was a typo lol)

Comment: Agree: Best to prove $A \times B \neq \emptyset$ and $(A \neq \emptyset \land B \neq \emptyset)$ are equivalent, meaning their negations are also equivalent.

Comment: How does $(x,y)\in \emptyset$ imply that $x \in \emptyset$ or $y\in \emptyset$?  (there is *one* vacuous reason but if you go that route you should explain in greater detail). At any rate it's much easier to do the contrapositive:  If neither $A$ nor $B$ is empty then $A\times B$ is not empty.

Comment: If $(x,y)\in \emptyset$ then $x = 100$ and $y=\text{a pink elephant}$ is a valid conclusion, as is the conclusion $A=\mathbb R$ and $B=[\sqrt{\pi}, 16.39]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's unclear what reasoning you are using in the highlighted step, or in the line that follows. The logic behind the second part of the proof is also obscure. In particular, the step from the fourth to the fifth line makes little sense to me. It seems to me that you are making formal manipulations about whose meaning you are not entirely certain.

The key point is the fact that **there is no $x$ such that $x \in \emptyset$**. That's literally the definition of the empty set. Consequently, it does not really make sense to start your proof by assuming that $x \in \emptyset$.

Instead of proving that $A \times B = \emptyset$ if and only if $A = \emptyset$ or $B = \emptyset$, you can (by elementary propositional logic) prove that $A \times B \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$. In plain English, $A \times B$ is non-empty (contains some element) if and only if $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty (both contain some element).

But this is a triviality: if $A \times B$ is non-empty, then it contains some element of the form $(x, y)$ for some $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, so $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty. Conversely, if $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and contain, respectively, the elements $x$ and $y$, then $A \times B$ is non-empty because it contains the pair $(x, y)$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It seems the biggest problem is that I kept on trying to pull elements out of sets that have no elements, which doesn't make any sense. The contrapositives would've been the way to go. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've reattempted this taking in all of your very helpful suggestions (huge thank you!), so here's a new and improved proof:

**Proof:** We first show that if $A \times B = \emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ by showing that if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq \emptyset$ then $A\times B \neq \emptyset$:

Since $A\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$, $A$ and $B$ have at least one element. 
Let $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. 
By the definition of the cartesian product, $(x,y)\in A\times B$.
Since $A\times B$ has at least one element, $A\times B \neq \emptyset$.
$\therefore$ if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq \emptyset$ then $A\times B\neq\emptyset$ is true.
$\therefore$ by TT if $A\times B = \emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ is true.

We now show if $A= \emptyset$ or $B= \emptyset$ then $A\times B = \emptyset$ by showing that if $A\times B \neq \emptyset$ then $A\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq \emptyset$:

Since $A\times B \neq \emptyset$, $A\times B$ has at least one element.
Let $(x,y)\in A\times B$.
By the definition of the cartesian product, $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.
Since $A$ and $B$ have at least one element, $A\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$.
$\therefore$ if $A\times B\neq \emptyset$ then $A\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$ is true.
$\therefore$ by TT if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ then $A\times B = \emptyset$ is true.

$\therefore$ by TT $A\times B = \emptyset$ iff $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ is true. $\blacksquare$

Thoughts on this proof? Is it any clearer? Anywhere else I can improve?

Comment: The logic of it looks good to me. The only modification I would make is to omit the lines starting with the symbol ∴. They don't add anything to the proof. (If you do wish to keep them: it's not clear what "TT" is supposed to abbreviate. It would be clearer to say "by contraposition".)

Comment: @Pilcrow Sorry I should've clarified -- my teacher requires the formatting with the therefore symbols and saying "by TT", meaning "truth table," for my Methods of Proof class. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Pilcrow it's weird, I know! lol